# Delete Entire Rows from multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with a vba code that will delete and entire row from a different sheet from the currently active one.

The code uses a userform to delete a row based upon a serial number entered into a text box. The rows to delete are duplicated on the sheet the userform is activated from as well as another. Below is an example I have tried which will delete the row of the current sheet but sends back an error for the second portion of code in the Else command.

```
Private Sub ScrapButton_Click()

Dim RTCNumber As String
RTCNumber = RTCTextBox

MSG1 = MsgBox("Remove " + RTCTextBox + " from Lab Stock?", vbYesNo)

If MSG1 = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, Sheet6.Range("A:A"), 0)
    Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Dim Row2 As Integer
    Row2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, Sheet1.Range("A:A"), 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Row2).EntireRow.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I am probably missing something obvious but I am fairly new to vba. I have tried several options and can't get it to work using a Worksheet.Activate function.

Thanks in advance.

James

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ScrapButton_Click()

  Dim RTCNumber As Double
  Dim Row2 As Variant
  Dim Row1 As Variant
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws6 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ws6 = wb.Sheets("Sheet6")

RTCNumber = RTCTextBox

MSG1 = MsgBox("Remove " & RTCNumber & " from Lab Stock?", vbYesNo)

If MSG1 = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else

    Row1 = ws6.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, ws6.Range("A:A"), 0)
    ws6.Rows(Row1).EntireRow.Delete


    Row2 = ws1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, ws1.Range("A:A"), 0)
    ws1.Rows(Row2).EntireRow.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to CLng the first argument of your match function. That works for me.

Had to remove WorksheetFunction on my version of Excel, but I don't know if that's the case on your machine, so I left it in.

And then, as manu stated in his answer, I added Sheet references.

```
Private Sub ScrapButton_Click()

Dim RTCNumber As String
RTCNumber = RTCTextBox

MSG1 = MsgBox("Remove " + RTCTextBox + " from Lab Stock?", vbYesNo)

If MSG1 = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Clng(RTCNumber), Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A"), 0)
    Rows(Row).EntireRow.Delete
    Dim Row2 As Integer
    Row2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Clng(RTCNumber), Sheets("Sheets1").Range("A:A"), 0)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(Row2).EntireRow.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use more simple way to achieve required results using `range.find` method.
So, your code can looks like this:

```
Private Sub ScrapButton_Click()
    Dim RTCNumber As String
    Dim Cl As Range
    RTCNumber = RTCTextBox

    msg1 = MsgBox("Remove " + RTCTextBox + " from Lab Stock?", vbYesNo)

    If msg1 = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
           Set Cl = .[A:A].Find(RTCNumber, , xlValues, xlWhole)
           If Not Cl Is Nothing Then Cl.EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        With Sheets("Sheet6")
           Set Cl = .[A:A].Find(RTCNumber, , xlValues, xlWhole)
           If Not Cl Is Nothing Then Cl.EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If you still prefer usage of `worksheetfunction` then you shall know that if `worksheetfunction.match` couldn't find the search value then it will return error, `worksheetfunction`s shall be used only with error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, thanks for the help!

Managed to get it working with Manu's answer with a couple tiny tweaks. It ended up like this:

```
Private Sub ScrapButton_Click()

  Dim RTCNumber As String
  Dim Row2 As Variant
  Dim Row1 As Variant
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Dim ws6 As Worksheet

  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Lab Stock")
  Set ws6 = wb.Worksheets("Scrap")

RTCNumber = RTCTextBox

MSG1 = MsgBox("Remove " & RTCNumber & " from Lab Stock?", vbYesNo)

If MSG1 = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
Else

    Row1 = ws6.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, ws6.Range("A:A"), 0)
    ws6.Rows(Row1).EntireRow.Delete


    Row2 = ws1.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(RTCNumber, ws1.Range("A:A"), 0)
ws1.Rows(Row2).EntireRow.Delete

End If

End Sub
```

Much, much appreciated!